# Flutter ValueNotifier notifyListeners twice

Tags: flutter, observable, changenotifier

I use `ValueNotifier` in Flutter and use `setValue` when data changed.

```
ValueNotifier<GameResultMessage?> gameResultMessage = ValueNotifier(null);
//
gameResultMessage.value = gameResultMessage;
```

`setValue` source code

```
  set value(T newValue) {
    if (_value == newValue) {
      return;
    }
    _value = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

I want to notify observer everytime whatever data is new or old.
(Run some animation)

But when I call `notifyListeners()` animation will run twice.
If I don't call `notifyListeners()`, animation won't run when data not changed.

How to solve it?

Comment: so the `value` setter is a part of custom `ChangeNotifier` implementing `ValueListenable` or something? if so, why do you use `ValueNotifier` and not your class?

Comment: @pskink yes because `ValueNotifier` has callback listener and I use it in other class.